# Puppeteer intercept page ws

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, devtools

Is it real to listen ws connections on page in puppeteer?
I want to write something like this:

```
page.on('request', (request) => {
  // it exists
  ...
})

page.on('ws-message-request', (message) => {
  ...
})

page.on('ws-message-response', (message) => {
  ...
})
```

But I haven't seen this in puppeteer api docs.

I tried to do it manually through devtools page like here.
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3699

Are there any easier ways to perform that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty nice solution.

```
const client = await myPage.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.enable');
client.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', ({ requestId, timestamp, response }) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```